# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/pom.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, maven

I am making an android app where I am using these libraries:

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4"
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1"
```

but it is giving an error:

> com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK
>   META-INF/maven/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/pom.xml     File1:
>   C:\Users\Vivek\projectX\app\libs\httpmime-4.4.1.jar   File2:
>   C:\Users\Vivek.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.4.1\2f8757f5ac5e38f46c794e5229d1f3c522e9b1df\httpmime-4.4.1.jar

So I searched and found a solution using:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
}
```

But it is again showing the same error. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827885/android-studio-0-4-duplicate-files-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt

Comment: add `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'`

Comment: i used it earlier and it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36978570/5545429

Comment: it is giving me a warning like           In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below packagingOptions  in your **build.gradle**.

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'httpcore-4.4.4'
    exclude 'httpmime-4.4.1'
}
```

If you have same issue you can try to add packagingOption like that

```
  exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/pom.xml'
```

For more information refer link  [refer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912459/duplicate-lib-file-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt-error-in-andorid-studio)

Comment: In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.